# Is there a way to view (through the local url) partial html templates while incorporating the main index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

Is there a way to view (through the local url) partial html templates while incorporating the main index.html?

I am trying to quickly access my partial html templates on my local so I can view them without having to copy and paste them into the main html.

I know how to do this with a framework such as swig and Angular... but I was hoping there would be a way to access them through the url while incorporating the index.html at the same time (such as adding #include)...

example of what I was hoping would work:

```
http://localhost:8000/#include/partials/feature.html
```

Right now I can go to:

```
http://localhost:8000/partials/feature.html
```

- ***But the css and js are not being pulled into the view (which are defined in index.html***

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think u want something like this-

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a frame work to accomplish this. Is that possible?

Comment: I had tried that before, I can confirm you that, that is possible (with AJAX) but code will not be so maintainable if you do that. So using AngularJS is perfect for that.